# Finding the path of an image file inside a monomac project

Tags: c#, path, mono, monodevelop, monomac

I am new to mono and monomac and i got stuck with something that i hope should be really easy to fix.

In my application i want to change some images at runtime, so i created an "Images" folder with my pics inside the root of the project.
But when i try to change the image in my code the image can't be found, so i think i'm writing the wrong path.

I try to get the image like this:

```
NSImage image = new NSImage("Images/image2.jpg"); // I tried with different paths but nothing changed...
pic1.Image = image;
```

If i use the full path to the image, everything work fine, but i need to use a relative one.
How should i get the right relative path?

I'm using Monodevelop.

Thanks.

Comment: 2 Suggestions.  First, `@"Images\image2.jpg"`.  Second, relative paths are usually relative to the current directory.  Find out what the current directory is.  `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

Comment: MonoMac runs on Mac OS X, so the path separator is indeed '/'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [NSBundle.PathForResourceAbsolute](http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoMac.Foundation.NSBundle.PathForResourceAbsolute%20%28string,%20string,%20string%29) method to locate the image, then load it.

Answer (score 1):

In my own project I looked up the MonoMac samples on Github and I found one that also [loads images at runtime](https://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/master/samples/ButtonMadness/TestWindowController.cs#L55).

They simply do a call to:

```
var myImage = NSImage.ImageNamed ("some.png");
```

I've placed my images in my project inside a sub folder "/Images" and this function still successfully loads my images.

So maybe this could be a solution to your issue, too.

Answer (score 1):

You also use System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) to get resources path.